# How to split a text file into blocks with 10+ characters without dividing words using sed in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I want to come up with a sed command where once every 10 character will look for the nearest space and substitute it with "|"

I tried `sed -E -e 's/ /|/\( *?[0-9a-zA-Z]*\)\{10,\}' new.file`, but it shows errors.

Example input:

```
Hello there! How are you? I am trying to figure this out.
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello there!|How are you?|I am trying|to figure this|out.
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for given sample:

```sh
$ sed -E 's/(.{10}[^ ]*) /\1|/g' ip.txt
Hello there!|How are you?|I am trying|to figure this|out.
```

- `(.{10}[^ ]*)` this matches 10 characters, followed by any non-space characters
- then a space is matched
- `\1|` put back captured portion and a `|` character

Comment: It works just as I wanted it to and I was struggling with it for a day. Thank you very much!
And thank you for editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon [Sundeep's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67905292/3832970), you may

- Add support for any whitespace by replacing spaces with `[[:space:]]` and non-space with `[^[:space:]]`
- Replace any chunk of one or more whitespace with a pipe if you add `+` (POSIX ERE) or `\{1,\}` (POSIX BRE).

You can use

```
sed 's/\(.\{10\}[^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\1|/g' ip.txt
sed -E 's/(.{10}[^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]+/\1|/g' ip.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/IITbRJ):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Hello there! How are you? I am trying to figure this out.'
sed 's/\(.\{10\}[^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\1|/g' <<< "$s"
sed -E 's/(.{10}[^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]+/\1|/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Hello there!|How are you?|I am trying|to figure this|out.
Hello there!|How are you?|I am trying|to figure this|out.
```